# Cloud Run disable old revision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run, traffic, revision

Is there a way to tell Cloud Run that it shouldn't use an old revision anymore?

After I deploy a new revision of my service, I'm using the update-traffic command and successfully setting 100% of the traffic to go to the new revision but the UI still shows the old version as "serving traffic"(although it's 0%) which also prevent the latest version to scale up to the max-instances option(which is the real problem).

[image]

Comment: Actually, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/managing/revisions): "Non-serving revisions do not consume any resources and are not billed".

Comment: Correct, the thing is that the old revision looks to stay as "serving"(the green icon on the screenshot) although it has 0% traffic. Another proof that it stays as the serving is that when I try to delete the revision with 0% traffic it complains with the error "you cannot delete revisions that are serving traffic".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This occurs when you have tag (Revision URL) on your revisions

[image]

Delete it and the revision icon will turn to grey again.

Comment: Having the tag there makes the revision "accessible" which leaves it as "serving traffic"

Answer (score 1):

If a revision has **one or more tags**, **the revision is still serving traffic** even if **"0%" traffic** is set to the revision as shown below:

[image]

Then, If a revision doesn't have **any tags** and **"0%" traffic** is set to the revision, **the revision is not serving traffic** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, **a revision is deletable** if the revision is not **the latest** and doesn't have **any tags** and **"0%" traffic** is set to the revision as shown below:

[image]